# How to delete a file in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Hello guys am new to Sails.js, here I have files created in following structure

```
--.tmp
   /--public
      /--dir1
         /--dir2
            /--avatar.jpg
            /--banner.jpg
```

**I want solution for**

> Case:1 - DELETE only avatar.jpg
>
> Case:2 - DELETE all existing images along with the directory "dir2 "

**I have tried :**

In controller

`var fs = require('fs');
fs.unlink(path_to_file)`
*But unfortunately could not make the filepath right.*

Please help me out any possible solutions for the above two problem cases.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For second case:

```
deleteFolderRecursive = (path) ->
  if fs.existsSync(path)
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach (file,index) ->
      curPath = path + "/" + file
      if fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()
        deleteFolderRecursive curPath
      else
        fs.unlinkSync curPath
    fs.rmdirSync path

dir = './tmp/public/dir1/dir2'
deleteFolderRecursive dir
```

Alternatively you can try changing directory to:

```
let dir = __dirname + '/tmp/public/dir1/dir2';
```

Or you can also try to add few `/..` before `/tmp` until your code works and deletes files correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Daniel, I will try your code, but I badly need an answer to the first case. pls suggest if you know something

Comment: So try changing value of variable `path_to_file` to correct path - for example you could maybe try: `fs.unlink(__dirname + '/.tmp/public/dir1/dir2')` or you can also try to add few `/..` before `/.tmp` until your code works and deletes files correctly.